# How does Java triangulate a Path2D?

Tags: java, graphics, bezier, triangulation, truetype

I'm developing an application that parses glyph data from a TrueType Font and converts it into polygons for rendering using OpenGL ES 2.0.

I've managed to convert the glyph data into discrete instructions such as `MOVE_TO`, `LINE_TO`, `QUAD_TO` and `CLOSE`, similar to Java's `Path2D` class. I then [triangulate](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html) these paths for rendering.

The problem I am having is that I seem to be handling these instructions in a non-standard way, since I can effectively render some fonts but fail to render others, as shown below. After some testing it seems to be the decision making logic I'm using when moving between `LINE_TO` and `BEZIER_TO` instructions, but I cannot find a sequence that is compatible with both fonts.

Is there any online documentation available on how Java's `Path2D` data is triangulated?

*1. A correctly rendered glyph ('c').*

[image: A correctly rendered character.]

*2. An incorrectly rendered glyph, from a different font ('c').*

[image: An incorrectly rendered character.]

In the snippet below, I am choosing the points to plot for triangulation. Whether we're on the inside or outside of the curve, we plot the ends of the Bezier curve or the Bezier control point. The Bezier curves are correctly rendered separately to this code.

```
switch(lVectorPathComponent) {
        case MOVE_TO   :
            /* Append the current vertex to PolygonPoints. */
            if((lLastPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.BEZIER_TO || lLastPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.MOVE_TO)) {
                lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 1], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 2]));
            }
            /* Initialize the start location of the path. */
            lStartX = pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 1];
            lStartY = pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 2];
        break;
        case LINE_TO   : 
            if(lLastPathComponent != EVectorPathComponent.MOVE_TO) {
                lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 1], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 2]));
            }
            else {
                if((lNextPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.LINE_TO || lNextPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.BEZIER_TO)) {
                    lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 1], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 2]));
                }
            }
        break;
        case BEZIER_TO : 
            if(VectorPathGlobal.onCalculateBezierDirection(pVectorPath, i) == pVectorPath.getWindingOrder()) {
                if(!(lLastPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.LINE_TO && lNextPathComponent == EVectorPathComponent.BEZIER_TO)) {
                    lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i - 2], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i - 1])); /* Last X, Y */
                    lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 1], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 2])); /* Control Point */
                    lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 3], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 4])); /* Bezier end X, Y */
                }
            }
            else {
                lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 3], pVectorPath.getPathData()[i + 4]));
            }
        break;
        case CLOSE     : 
            lPolygonPoints.add(new PolygonPoint(lStartX, lStartY));
        break;
    }
}
```

The correctly rendered curve consists of these commands:

```
MOVE_TO x:121.0 y:682.0
BEZIER_TO cx:121.0 cy:840.0 x:164.0 y:969.0
BEZIER_TO cx:208.0 cy:1098.0 x:289.0 y:1189.0
BEZIER_TO cx:370.0 cy:1281.0 x:485.0 y:1330.0
BEZIER_TO cx:601.0 cy:1380.0 x:746.0 y:1380.0
BEZIER_TO cx:797.0 cy:1380.0 x:838.0 y:1374.0
BEZIER_TO cx:880.0 cy:1369.0 x:914.0 y:1360.0
BEZIER_TO cx:949.0 cy:1351.0 x:978.0 y:1339.0
BEZIER_TO cx:1007.0 cy:1327.0 x:1033.0 y:1314.0
LINE_TO x:978.0 y:1184.0
BEZIER_TO cx:929.0 cy:1207.0 x:872.0 y:1220.0
BEZIER_TO cx:816.0 cy:1234.0 x:746.0 y:1234.0
BEZIER_TO cx:650.0 cy:1234.0 x:571.0 y:1202.0
BEZIER_TO cx:492.0 cy:1170.0 x:435.0 y:1102.0
BEZIER_TO cx:379.0 cy:1035.0 x:348.0 y:931.0
BEZIER_TO cx:317.0 cy:827.0 x:317.0 y:682.0
BEZIER_TO cx:317.0 cy:537.0 x:349.0 y:432.0
BEZIER_TO cx:382.0 cy:327.0 x:441.0 y:259.0
BEZIER_TO cx:500.0 cy:191.0 x:583.0 y:158.0
BEZIER_TO cx:666.0 cy:126.0 x:768.0 y:126.0
BEZIER_TO cx:811.0 cy:126.0 x:847.0 y:131.0
BEZIER_TO cx:884.0 cy:137.0 x:915.0 y:146.0
BEZIER_TO cx:946.0 cy:155.0 x:972.0 y:165.0
BEZIER_TO cx:998.0 cy:176.0 x:1020.0 y:186.0
LINE_TO x:1062.0 y:58.0
BEZIER_TO cx:1009.0 cy:25.0 x:933.0 y:2.0
BEZIER_TO cx:858.0 cy:-20.0 x:746.0 y:-20.0
BEZIER_TO cx:601.0 cy:-20.0 x:485.0 y:30.0
BEZIER_TO cx:370.0 cy:81.0 x:289.0 y:173.0
BEZIER_TO cx:208.0 cy:265.0 x:164.0 y:394.0
BEZIER_TO cx:121.0 cy:524.0 x:121.0 y:682.0
```

The incorrectly rendered curve uses these:

```
MOVE_TO x:831.0 y:1391.0
BEZIER_TO cx:556.0 cy:1391.0 x:398.0 y:1215.0
BEZIER_TO cx:240.0 cy:1039.0 x:240.0 y:733.0
BEZIER_TO cx:240.0 cy:420.0 x:389.0 y:247.0
BEZIER_TO cx:538.0 cy:74.0 x:815.0 y:74.0
BEZIER_TO cx:999.0 cy:74.0 x:1153.0 y:121.0
LINE_TO x:1153.0 y:31.0
BEZIER_TO cx:1008.0 cy:-20.0 x:791.0 y:-20.0
BEZIER_TO cx:483.0 cy:-20.0 x:306.0 y:179.0
BEZIER_TO cx:129.0 cy:378.0 x:129.0 y:735.0
BEZIER_TO cx:129.0 cy:958.0 x:213.0 y:1128.0
BEZIER_TO cx:298.0 cy:1298.0 x:456.0 y:1390.0
BEZIER_TO cx:615.0 cy:1483.0 x:825.0 y:1483.0
BEZIER_TO cx:1039.0 cy:1483.0 x:1208.0 y:1403.0
LINE_TO x:1167.0 y:1311.0
BEZIER_TO cx:1007.0 cy:1391.0 x:831.0 y:1391.0
```

Comment: Consider showing a relevant snippet of what you tried. Sample output would help as well.

Comment: @Jongware I've added the relevant snippet. Hopefully this doesn't confuse things!

Comment: I always find it illuminating to see a textual representation of what such output routines *thinks* it is doing. Can you add `print` lines for each command, and the output for both good and bad decodings?

Comment: @Dawnkeeper If you check out this gem, you'll see an image of the triangles used to draw a letter 'e': http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch25.html

I'm trying to iterate around the path and throw away the points necessary in order to achieve triangulation. You can see that points on the outside use the ends of the curves, whereas points on the inside use all of the control points. Thanks for the link, but I've checked this source before but I couldn't find any concrete definitions of how the curves are parsed.

Comment: FYI I am wondering if you are treating the Starting point correctly, since the second image seems to "link" to the character origin. Hence my request for a detailed output trace.

Comment: @AlexT. The snippet enlightened me to being on the wrong track. But thanks for the link. Looks interesting.

Comment: I've added the relevant output. (This question sure is getting long!) The only real difference between the two is the way they end; the incorrect curve ends with a `LINE_TO` and a `BEZIER_TO`. I've tried all kinds of combinations to eliminate the error, but it introduces incompatible changes with the correctly rendered font. This is why I'm after some kind of specification!

Comment: I've also provided the co-ordinates to give you a better idea!

Comment: Have you tried to just connect the end points of each step with lines? Also there are some negative values in the 2nd part. Could this cause errors in your code?

Comment: I originally did, but this caused glyph artifacts. Good eye! But, negative values shouldn't matter as I render them directly irrespective of sign. The characters in the images have been scaled and translated to aid visibility, but this is after the vertex data has been produced.

Comment: Guys thanks for your help, but I think I've found the problem. It was to do with my calculation of the direction of the Bezier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the tessellation methods used in [LibTess2](https://github.com/memononen/libtess2) were compatible with Java's Path2D triangulation.

In my original question, the issue I was having was that for triangulation of my vertices I was using [Poly2Tri](http://code.google.com/p/poly2tri/), which doesn't support vertices that lie on the edge of the polygon; because of this issue, a few strange triangles were being generated that seemed to ramp down to the origin. LibTess2 also struggles to triangulate non-simple polygons, however upon detection of conflicting vertices, it allows the user to provide a method for resolving the conflict via it's `combine()` method callback. By making an equality between conflicting vertices, erroneous tessellation could be resolved, which results in a correctly triangulated glyph. [earcut-j](https://github.com/Cawfree/earcut-j) is also robust enough to handle these vertices.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the code is fine. The code below uses the standard Path2D quadTo/curveTo. Maybe it has something to do with even-odd winding rules or such.

```
public class JavaGUI extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame f = new JFrame("Glyphs");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new JavaGUI());
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            f.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public JavaGUI() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 600));
        setBackground(new Color(0xDDEEFF));
    }

    private double x0;
    private double y0;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        final String aString = "c";
        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        double scale = 0.25;
        g2d.translate(100, 100);
        g2d.scale(scale, scale);

        Path2D.Double path = new Path2D.Double(); // May add rule and such.

        moveTo(path, 121.0, 682.0);
        bezierTo(path, 121.0, 840.0, 164.0, 969.0);
        bezierTo(path, 208.0, 1098.0, 289.0, 1189.0);
        bezierTo(path, 370.0, 1281.0, 485.0, 1330.0);
        bezierTo(path, 601.0, 1380.0, 746.0, 1380.0);
        bezierTo(path, 797.0, 1380.0, 838.0, 1374.0);
        bezierTo(path, 880.0, 1369.0, 914.0, 1360.0);
        bezierTo(path, 949.0, 1351.0, 978.0, 1339.0);
        bezierTo(path, 1007.0, 1327.0, 1033.0, 1314.0);
        lineTo(path, 978.0, 1184.0);
        bezierTo(path, 929.0, 1207.0, 872.0, 1220.0);
        bezierTo(path, 816.0, 1234.0, 746.0, 1234.0);
        bezierTo(path, 650.0, 1234.0, 571.0, 1202.0);
        bezierTo(path, 492.0, 1170.0, 435.0, 1102.0);
        bezierTo(path, 379.0, 1035.0, 348.0, 931.0);
        bezierTo(path, 317.0, 827.0, 317.0, 682.0);
        bezierTo(path, 317.0, 537.0, 349.0, 432.0);
        bezierTo(path, 382.0, 327.0, 441.0, 259.0);
        bezierTo(path, 500.0, 191.0, 583.0, 158.0);
        bezierTo(path, 666.0, 126.0, 768.0, 126.0);
        bezierTo(path, 811.0, 126.0, 847.0, 131.0);
        bezierTo(path, 884.0, 137.0, 915.0, 146.0);
        bezierTo(path, 946.0, 155.0, 972.0, 165.0);
        bezierTo(path, 998.0, 176.0, 1020.0, 186.0);
        lineTo(path, 1062.0, 58.0);
        bezierTo(path, 1009.0, 25.0, 933.0, 2.0);
        bezierTo(path, 858.0, -20.0, 746.0, -20.0);
        bezierTo(path, 601.0, -20.0, 485.0, 30.0);
        bezierTo(path, 370.0, 81.0, 289.0, 173.0);
        bezierTo(path, 208.0, 265.0, 164.0, 394.0);
        bezierTo(path, 121.0, 524.0, 121.0, 682.0);

        path.closePath();

        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2d.fill(path);

        // ------

        path = new Path2D.Double(); // May add rule and such.

        moveTo(path, 831.0, 1391.0);
        bezierTo(path, 556.0, 1391.0, 398.0, 1215.0);
        bezierTo(path, 240.0, 1039.0, 240.0, 733.0);
        bezierTo(path, 240.0, 420.0, 389.0, 247.0);
        bezierTo(path, 538.0, 74.0, 815.0, 74.0);
        bezierTo(path, 999.0, 74.0, 1153.0, 121.0);
        lineTo(path, 1153.0, 31.0);
        bezierTo(path, 1008.0, -20.0, 791.0, -20.0);
        bezierTo(path, 483.0, -20.0, 306.0, 179.0);
        bezierTo(path, 129.0, 378.0, 129.0, 735.0);
        bezierTo(path, 129.0, 958.0, 213.0, 1128.0);
        bezierTo(path, 298.0, 1298.0, 456.0, 1390.0);
        bezierTo(path, 615.0, 1483.0, 825.0, 1483.0);
        bezierTo(path, 1039.0, 1483.0, 1208.0, 1403.0);
        lineTo(path, 1167.0, 1311.0);
        bezierTo(path, 1007.0, 1391.0, 831.0, 1391.0        );

        path.closePath();

        g2d.setColor(new Color(0x8800CC00, true));
        g2d.fill(path);

        g2d.scale(1/scale, 1/scale);
    }

    private void bezierTo(Path2D.Double path, double cx, double cy,
            double x, double y) {
        path.quadTo(cx, cy, x, y);
        //path.curveTo(x0, y0, cx, cy, x, y);
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
    }

    private void moveTo(Path2D.Double path, double x, double y) {
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
    }

    private void lineTo(Path2D.Double path, double x, double y) {
        path.lineTo(x, y);
        x0 = x;
        y0 = y;
    }
}
```

[image: Two glyphs of both a "c"]

Comment: I didn't consider that as a method for debugging, nice!